# Как сделать переключатель валют для ACF (без WooCommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Нашёл один плагин и тот платный, есть вариант как это руками склепать на крайняк? или какие-то плагины которые подойдут для ACF полей?

Нужен переключатель, по типу переключателя языков и в случае его переключения, валюта будет заменена в контенте на странице, a само значение валюты, это ACF поле.

Comment: Может немного объясните, что значит "конвертер валют для ACF"?

Comment: @Simon очень рад что Вы всегда отписываете мне) нужен свитчер, аля переключатель языков polylang, извините что не расписал в вопросе, затупил немного

Comment: Ну понятнее от этого не стало) Вам нужен переключатель, по типу переключателя языков и в случае его переключения, валюта будет заменена в контенте на странице (само значение валюты, как я понял, это ACF поле)?

Comment: @Simon вот лучше Вас сейчас никто бы не объяснил что мне надо) в точку

Comment: Ну конкретно какого-то плагина который делал бы именно то что Вам нужно, я не встречал. Если с 0, то я написал бы собственный плагин, который бы 1 раз в сутки дергал бы курс валют с нужного мне сервиса при помощи wp cron, а при переключении вот этого переключателя, при помощи ajax подменял бы цену с перерасчетом ее на бекенде. Это если в общих чертах.

Comment: @Simon к сожалению нужно обойтись без кастомных плагинов, очень вжат в сроки